# Sequence dense in $\mathbb R$

Tags: number-theory

I recently came accross the proof of "$\{ \frac{p_i}{p_j}|p_i,p_j $ is prime $ \}$ is dense in $\mathbb Q^+$, where $\mathbb Q^+$ is the set of positive rational numbers". So, I wonder is there any sequence $\langle x_n \rangle _{n\in\mathbb N}$  in $\mathbb N$ such that $\sum \frac{1}{x_n}$ is convergent and $\{ \frac{x_m}{x_n}|m,n\in \mathbb N \}$ is dense in $\mathbb Q^+$? Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not take $x_i=p_i^2$? The square of a dense set of positive numbers is still dense. Then the sum of the reciprocals converges.

More simply, as suggested by Greg Martin, we can take $x_i=i^2$.

Comment: Indeed this argument shows that $x_i = i^2$ is another example, a more elementary one.

Comment: @Greg That is true. I didn't think of that because I was just extending the example.

Comment: I didn't think of it either, until I read your answer—so in my view the credit is yours!

Comment: Ohh. God..That is really simple. I'm sorry for not seeing it this way.